# gitlab SSL configuration / certificate verification failed

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, composer

I have my own gitlab server, now secured with an letsencrypt SSL certificate.

Now, I want to publish some packages via packagist. But when I enter the git repository url in packagist, I got the following error message (urls changed):

```
Uncaught Exception: [RuntimeException] Failed to execute git clone --mirror 'https://url.de/gituser/repository.git' '/home/composer/.composer/cache/vcs/https---url.de-gituser-repository' Cloning into bare repository '/home/composer/.composer/cache/vcs/https---url.de-gituser-repository'... fatal: unable to access 'https://url.de/gituser/repository.git': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
```

Each browser accepts the certificate. But not composer/packagist.

Any Ideas why?

Comment: Check the site with [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html). My guess is missing intermediate certificate, i.e. "chain issues" in the report. Browsers often work around such misconfiguration.

Comment: Ok, Done. "Chain issues" is "incomplete". And on "Certification Paths
Path #1: Trusted" under "2." I read "extra download". What means that?

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I just found my mistake. I have used `cert.pem` instead of `fullchain.pem`.

Explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34189199/how-do-i-use-let-s-encrypt-with-gitlab

Comment: Nice catch, had the exact same issue.